# Will different versions of dynamic link libraries conflict with each other?

Tags: dll, shared-libraries

I wrote a dynamic link library for customers to use. My dynamic link library itself will dynamically link to third-party libraries such as opencv and TBB. The customer's executable program links to the dynamic link library I provided, and the customer's executable program itself will also link to the same third-party libraries such as opencv and TBB but with different versions. Will there be any conflicts? (Can it be linked to the correct version? For example, the dynamic link library I provided should be linked to opencv v1.0, and the customer's own executable program should be linked to opencv v2.0).

I saw that all opencv dlls have suffixes, such as opencv_1.dll, opencv_2.dll. Will this help link to the correct version?

What about the linux platform?

I search but with no answers.